# After adding Zendesk Android SDK compile group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk', version: '1.11.0.1' getting duplicate entry error

Tags: android, zendesk

I've added Zendesk Android dependency. After adding it getting duplicate entry ZipException:

Here are the logs:

Error:Execution failed for task ':App:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/os/EnvironmentCompatKitKat.class

Here is the gradle file (module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':Modules:InstaRydeDataDroid')
    compile project(':Modules:InstaRydeFacebookSDK')
    compile project(':Modules:InstaRydeSmoothProgressBar')
    compile project(':InstaRydeWePaySDK')
    //compile project(':Modules:InstaRyde_google-play-services_lib')
    compile project(':googlemapssdkm4b_lib')
    compile files('libs/HERE-sdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/HERE-sdk-javadoc.jar')
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'gson'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.1.1'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.+'
    compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:data:1.+'
    compile 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.2-beta-1'
    compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub:3.7.5'
    compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.2"
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk', version: '1.11.0.1'

    compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0") {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0") {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0") {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.instaryde.android"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 380
        versionName "3.4.3"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk false
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets', 'src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude  'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude  'build-data.properties'
    }
}
```

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: Have `exclude module: 'support-v4'` ?

Comment: Yup having exclude module: 'support-v4' but not with Zendesk dependency. Having it with play-services dependencies.

Comment: Gradle file contents added in description above.

Comment: anything else you want? @IntelliJAmiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly remove

- **`exclude module: 'support-v4'`**.
- **all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'**

**Use**

```
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.5.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Restart`** IDE.

**`FYI`**

You should use [**`LATEST`**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) version, Your **`VERSION 7.5.0`** too old **(May 2015 - version 7.5)** or Set Minimum **`9.4.0`**.

Comment: Removed exclude module: 'support-v4'. Done Clean-Rebuild-Restart IDE. But issue is not resolved yet.

Comment: Probably absent this version. Use `10.2.0`

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':App:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper$1.class

Comment: @AkhtarKhan Make sure you DELETE from `v4 Library`  local LIB folder

Comment: Getting above duplicate entry error after removing exclude module: 'support-v4'

Comment: @AkhtarKhan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858292/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-support-v4-printhelper1-class

Comment: @AkhtarKhan Did you remove this line ? `all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'`

Comment: Yes I've removed all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'

Comment: One of my modules LIB folder was having android-support-v4.jar. I've deleted it.

Comment: After deleting it, getting below errors:

Error:(34, 30) error: package android.support.v4.app does not exist
Error:(1092, 62) error: cannot find symbol class Fragment

Comment: @AkhtarKhan set `com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+`

Comment: Yup. It works Great. Thanks alot for your help. Was stuck with it from last 2 days. Thanks Again !!